# Js Active link not working in php when I am trying to use GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used js for active link,this is working fine for below line

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="list-group-item menu cp_btns" target="blank" ><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

But for this below line this is working only for loading time, after load the page it's not working.

```
<a href="index.php?U=<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" class="list-group-item menu cp_btns" ><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

Here my URL is index.php?U=Google

I have used this js code here

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a.cp_btns').click(function(){
            $('a.cp_btns.active').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
             });
            });
</script>
```

Have there any solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Please include screenshots of both links, upload images to `imgur.com`

Comment: The difference that I see is that the second one is without target="_blank" so it opens in same window (stopping scripts, rendering etc.). Click handler probably works but doesn't have effect as after click browser goes to new page.

Comment: Yes you are right.IF I use target="blank" this is working ! but without use blank this is not working,after load the page.Why this is happening? I have used same sidebar in all page.